# UserControl won't show in Excel Ribbon?

Tags: c#, excel

I have made an excel addIn using Visual Studio and C#. I have a ribbon designer, along with a user control that I have made, very basic, it just has a label, a text box and a button. Basically, I want the button in my ribbon to call my userform, which I have coded in my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        UC_License uc = new UC_License();
        uc.Show();
        if (uc.success() == true)
        {
            this.lbl_Lisence.Label = lbl_Lisence.Label + " - Correct.";
        }
        else if (uc.success() == false)
        {
            this.lbl_Lisence.Label = lbl_Lisence + " - Incorrect.";
        }
    }
```

Everything runs or compiles or builds fine (no errors) but when I open excel, my addIn is there, that's fine. But my user control does not show?

Is the excel ribbon only capable of using elements or components from the designer?

Quite lost.

Comment: Answer to this question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651849/how-to-instantiate-a-usercontrol-using-vb

With much thanx to DrDonut!