# How to instantiate a UserControl using VB?

Tags: vb.net, excel

**So** in C# to declare and instantiate a UserControl, you would go about it similar to this:

```
UserControl1 userCont = new UserControl1();
userCont.Show();
```

And this would show your user control named UserControl1.

This is the way you do it in C#, now how do you do this in VB?

Because I have coded an Excel Add In, and have put a userControl in the ribbon, but it does not want to show, and that project is in VB, not C#.

EDIT:

**Some explanation of my project:**

I have an Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO add-in project type. 
I have 3 classes, namely:
**UserControl1.vb** - as my userControl 
**Ribbon.vb** - as my ribbon class
**ThisAddIn.vb** - as the add in class

My userControl is rather simple, it has 3 buttons, a "Yes" button, a "No" button, and an "Add Tables" button. It has 1 listBox, and 12 checkboxes...

The Ribbon is also quite simple, I have 2 buttons in the Ribbon called "Show" and "Loop"...

The ThisAddIn class contains code that will make this add in work, such as methods and general functionality...

Okay so that's my classes...

**The goal of my project is:**

When the "Show" button is clicked, a CustomTaskPane will appear in excel on the right, inside this customTaskPane will be my userControl... 
*(This works)*
**Big thanks to DrDonut for his answer**

When the "Add Tables" button is clicked (in the userControl), I want excel to iterate through all the sheets, and add every listObject's name (tables name) to the listBox. 
*(The Loop and Add Tables button are the same)*

In C# I know you go:

```
this.ListBox1.Items.Add("Item 1");
```

And that will add an item to the listbox, the same principle is applied in VB, but with my ListBox sitting in my userControl which inherently sits in the CustomTaskPane, no items can seem to be added...
*(Adding items to the list box does not work)*

And with regards to the looping of tables, or retrieving their names, this doesn't work either...

*(This is what I really want to get going nicely)*

Hope this edit will shed some clarity on the situation...

**Some gritty information:**

OS: Windows 10 Pro (x64)

RAM: 32gb

CPU: i7-6700 @3.40ghz

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Microsoft Excel 2016 (x64)

Comment: That is not the way you do it in C#.  Adding the control to a parent with its Controls.Add() method is a hard requirement in any language.

Comment: Do you know how to code C# friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vb.net it's quite similar, for a task pan (the panel at the right side of an office application) it is:

```
Dim userControl as UserControl
Dim userTaskPane as Microsoft.office.tools.CustomTaskPane

userControl = new UserControl
userTaskPane = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(userControl, "Title")
userTaskPane.visible = true
```

Now it should show the panel.

Edit: Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942846.aspx

Edit 2: You also need to set the right references. Assuming that you use visual studio, go to the solution explorer -> Your project -> References. In my project these contain the following:

- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
- Microsoft.Office.Tools
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common
- Microsoft.Office.tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel
- Microsoft.Office.Tools.v4.0.Framework
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
- Office

I don't know if you need all of them, but for sure you will need some of them.

Comment: "Microsoft.office.tools.CustomTaskPane" - is not defined

And 

"'CustomTaskPanes' is not a member of 'Form1'.

Comment: Did you set the right references? Like Microsoft.Office.Tools etc?

Comment: If I type in Microsoft.  - onloy CSharp, SQLServer, VusualBasic and Win32 show up. No office

Comment: Apologies, I was in the wrong project lol, the only hickup here is "userTaskPane = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(userControl, "Title")" that line... It reckons that task panes are not members of the ribbon. 

- "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30456 'CustomTaskPanes' is not a member of 'Ribbon1'. SS_Load C:\Users\James\documents\...

Comment: Is your project defined as an vsto plugin?

Comment: All of those references were added by default, and yes I'm pretty sure this is a VSTO add in, are you using Visual Studio 2015? I know they've updated some things, like theres no longer a "SET" keyword.

Comment: Yes, I use 2015. Also, the CustomTaskPanes is a member of the ThisAddin class, which is created when you create a vsto plugin project. It is not a member of the ribbon class.

Comment: OH! Makes sense now, thank you kindly for your time!

Comment: I Am not sure, all I know is that the customTaskPanes are defined as an 'Microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpanescollection', so you could try to define and initialize it, but I am not sure what other stuff needs to be set right.

Comment: Inside the ThisAddIn.vb class, they say 'Me' is not valid within a module?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your code? Because 'Me' is a vb.net keyword that you should be able to use...

Comment: Sure, I'll do that now... Here's an exception that just got thrown: 
"An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: You are a genius friend! Thank you very much! Got my userControl to show up on the right!!!

Comment: So now, there's no way to make all this happen through a button click? As you say, the ribbon can't use these members, and you can't exactly put a button in the ThisAddIn.bv class :/

Comment: And I would vote your answer up but I apparently do not have enough rep

Comment: You're welcome! From your ribbon class, you can call a member function in your ThisAddin.vb class, from there you can create your pane.

Comment: DrDonut, sir. In my ThisAddIn.vb class, in the "ThisAddIn_Startup()" I have put your code to create a task pane and to load my userControl into it, and it works with the method being in the StartUp() function. But now, I have copied that code and made a public sub called showPane(), 

In my Ribbon class, on a button I do this: 
Dim tai As ThisAddIn
tai.showPane()

But get a null reference exception, what am I missing? Because in my mind, if it works in the ThisAddIn class, and if I take that code, make a public method, shouldn't it work if I inherit those members and methods? :/

Comment: Could you edit your question so I can see your code? I think you might call your 'thisAddin' class, instead of an instance of that class. So I think your call from your ribbon class should be: 'Globals.ThisAddin.showPane()' This way, there is no need to inherit, you can use your function in the ThisAddin class...

Comment: You are truly something extraordinary DrDonut! Did what you said and it works like a charm! I had done this: 

Dim tai as ThisAddIn
tai.showPane()

But got the NullReferenceException... Thought that would do the trick but clearly not. 

Do you know why your way works and my way doesn't? As far as my knowledge in C-sharp goes, if you instantiate a class, you can inherit it's members and functions, so I thought if I did that in VB, it would work the same? Not sure if I'm referencing wrong or what but thank you Doctor!

Comment: What I think happens is: at the start of your application, instance1 of ThisAddin is created, with all the data that belongs with it. When you call 'Dim tai as ThisAddIn', you create a new instance (instance2) but you don't initialize it, so the pane collection is still empty when you try to call a function on it. When you call Globals.ThisAddIn, you call instance1 which is initialized.

Comment: Hmm okay, makes sense, again, thank you for your time Doctor, find my profile for more questions soon (probably) haha. 

Got any idea on how to loop through all tables in a workbook? :/

Comment: Are you sure we don't work on the same project? 'For each sheet as Excel.worksheet in Application.activeworkbook.sheets' *Your code* Next'

Comment: Ha! If we did, I wouldn't be on StackOverFlow :P 

I too thought this would be an easy logical loop to come up like for each table in each sheet. But my knowledge on VB isn't so hot, they might be closely related but like I say, even twins are different.

I have "For Each ws In app.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets"
xlRange = app.ActiveCell
            Dim strListObjectName = xlRange.ListObject.Name
            uc.ListBox1.Items.Add(strListObjectName)
            MsgBox(strListObjectName)

The message box appears 5 times, but there's only one sheet, with one table in it.

Comment: And my variables are - 

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
        Dim app As Excel.Application
        Dim xlRange As Excel.Range = Nothing

And Dim uc As UserControl1, 
        uc = New UserControl1

Comment: Also Doctor, with my listBox in that custom pane you made, I can't seem to add any items to it... 

Where I declare uc as UserControl1
To instantiate it is: uc = new UserControl1

to add listBox items is Items.Add(); so...

I go...

uc.ListBox1.Items.Add(app.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ToString())

But it does not work.., No idea why... A message box can tell me the name, but can't add it to the list box :/

MsgBox actually says System.__ComObject, excuse

Comment: Okay so this msgBox will display the table name, but can't be added to a listbox for some reason... Here's what I have - 

Dim app As Excel.Application,
Dim uc As UserControl1,
uc = New UserControl1,
Dim lob As Excel.ListObject,
lob = app.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1),
MsgBox(lob.Name)  ,
uc.ListBox1.Items.Add(lob.Name.ToString()),

(I've put commas at the end of each line to help)

No errors are thrown or anything, just the listbox remains empty

Comment: Hmm, for me the code becomes unclear now, could you edit your question, or post a new one and link it here so I can see it? What I think is wrong, is 'Dim app as Excel.Application', for this will create a new (empty) instance of an excel application, while you still have a perfectly valid one in Globals.ThisAddin.Application. Could you try using that one?

Comment: Not sure how to go about editing, my account here is somewhat disliked by the community by asking "bad questions" but little do they know, the related questions do not help me at all, anyways... 

I do assign a value to the xlApp by doing this: 

Try,     
xlApp=CType(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"),Excel.Application),     
Catch ex As Exception,     
MsgBox("Excel unavailable"),     
Exit Sub,     
End Try.     

This attaches excel to an instance of itself.

Comment: Why would you assign a value like that? You already have one in your thisAddin class. Also, does your sub end before your try statement? Also, I don't know exactly what these 'listObjects' are, and what they look like when converted to a string, do you know this? And asking 'good questions' is a craft that takes time to master...

Comment: Also, with 'The name of the tables', do you mean the name of the sheets in your workbook?

Comment: Initially the xlApp gets assigned a value of Null... Well actually it's "Nothing" in VB... But then I attach an instance of excel onto it, I find without that piece of code, I get a NullReferenceException... 

And DrDonut, a ListObject is a table as far as I know

And with regards to the table names, I really just mean getting the table's name... 

In excel, if you go to insert, table, and create one... In the design tab, you can see the table's name... Think you can also find it in the name manager if I'm not mistaken... I want the name in the design tab per each table...

Comment: And also Doctor, my knowledge on excels data model and object library isn't so hot... And I've gotten help with getting it to where it is now (my project), and I may not fully understand absolutely everything, but I do have a general idea of how things work. With the whole excel.application vibe? I have not a single idea what goes on there, all I know is that that "try" statement, fixed whatever problem I was facing.

Comment: Okay, I don't know anything about how to use these tables in vb.net. I suggest googling around, and if you cannot find it, ask a new question on: 'how to extract name of table from excel sheet'

Comment: Mmm, yeah I would post another question, but I'm "Not allowed" to... some bs but anyways, thank you again for your help Doctor! I see this being the end of this thread... Hope to catch you on other forum soon! :)